# swift - set UILabel without reload of custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is it possible to set a value for a UILabel in a custom UITableViewCell without reloading the cell?

I've tried many permutations of:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell1
cell.customLabel.text = "text goes here"
```

.. and I don't understand why this won't work.  I've got a UITextField in the UITableViewCell, and when I set the textField value I'd like only the label to update, but not reload the entire cell.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you try to launch cell.customLabel.setNeedsDisplay() after setting your text?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano - thanks, this works as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 cell.customLabel.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Comment: This answer is easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the `UIViews`, you need to put them in main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
   cell.customLabel.text = "text goes here"
})
```

Comment: Can you compromise cell constraints without reload the cell? i think is too dangerous..

Comment: Aw, I mistyped :/. Thanks @Lion